# Bounding the number of vertices in a graph from below using minimum degree and girth

Tags: graph-theory

I'm going through a graph theory book and apparently the number of vertices should be at least

- $1+\delta\sum\limits_{i=0}^{r-1}(\delta-1)^i$ for $girth=2r+1$
- $2\sum\limits_{i=0}^{r-1}(\delta-1)^i$ for $girth=2r$

Apparently it should be trivial to prove.

I'm really puzzled by the sums, especially the $(\delta-1)$ parts.

Any hints on how to prove this?

P.S. apparently it also holds for average degree. Again the proof was omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT (the ideas are given, you need to transform them into a clean proof)

1. Grow the graph from one single vertex, at each step make sure that the vertices of the previous step all get degree at least $\delta$.

In the first growth phase you add at least $\delta$ neighbours, since your start vertex has degree at least $\delta$.
If $r=1$ you are done, since you have $\delta+1$ vertices.

For the second growth phase you have (at least) $\delta$ vertices that have degree 1.
To bring them to degree delta you need to add $\delta-1$ edges to each of them.
Since the girth is at least 5, there can be no common neighbours for the new vertices,
so you create $\delta(\delta-1)$ new vertices.
If $r=2$ you are done.

etc.

2. Like 1, only the start is different: you do not start with a single vertex but with two adjacent vertices.

P.S. I know that the result also holds for average degree, but I do not know a simple proof.